# Emacs ligatures overwrite previous characters

Tags: fonts, emacs, ligature, fira-code

I'm setting up the Fira Code font/ligatures on Emacs 26 for Windows, according to the guide at https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Emacs-instructions#using-font-lock-keywords.

It creates the ligatures, but they are all shifted back. I'm guessing it's shifted one space per character in the ligature.

I tested using the text:

```
int test()
{
    ptr->field = (a == b) ? 1 : 2;

}

https://www.website.com
```

screenshot

[image: 1]

How do I correct this?

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: I did. The image is to show how it appears on the screen.

Comment: I just want to reassure you that you've asked a good question, and I wish I had an answer. My personal preference with editing code, though, is to steer clear of anything but fixed-pitch, serif typefaces. Having a predictable grid of characters is something I find helpful when navigating.